# set 2 axis on rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

```
    void LateUpdate () {
    if (thirdPersonView)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, camPos1.position, Time.deltaTime * smoothFollow);
        transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, camPos1.forward, Time.deltaTime * smoothFollow);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = camPos2.position;
        transform.forward = camPos2.forward;
    }
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("View"))
        thirdPersonView = !thirdPersonView;

    rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, -rotationY);
}
```

What I am trying to do is make the camera follow the player and when I use the mouse and moves it up and down the camera rotation should move too up and down. 
As you can see I have tried that but this is not working right beacouse of the line:

transform.forward = camPos2.forward;

I have tried to split the forward to 3 part: the X Y Z and sets the X to transform.rotation but it is not working too.
How can I make it work?